# Access to join table with has many through association in ActiveRecord Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

**I have**

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :operations 
end 

class Operation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :goods, through: :positions
end

class Good < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :operations, through: :positions
end
```

**I want**
`Request.where(goods: {code: '123'}` (in metacode)

**Comments**
I know that I can make a query like this:
`Request.includes(:operations).where(operations: {kind: 'acceptance'})`
But I can't figure out how to make this query for goods with proper `includes`.

**Updated: An Extract from Schema**

```
create_table "requests", force: :cascade do |t|
end

create_table "operations", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "kind"
  t.integer  "request_id"
end

create_table "goods", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.decimal  "purchase_price", precision: 12, scale: 2
end

create_table "positions", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "good_id"
  t.integer  "request_id"
  t.integer  "operation_id"
end
```

Comment: Can you post your schema.db ? Do you have relationship tables ?

Comment: @JérémyButtice I added an extract from schema.db. Yes, I have relationship tables and they work fine as far as I see. Thx.